# When calling notifydatasetchanged(), the adapter displays the old list items too along with new items

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-recyclerview

I'm getting the list from firebase and displaying it in a list view and when the delete button is clicked, I'm able to delete the item in firebase but the problem is on calling `notifydatasetchanged()`, the RecyclerView displays old items along with new items.

I need to know how to prevent RecyclerView from displaying old items and where should I call `notifydatasetchanged()`

```
public class CartRecyclerAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<CartRecyclerAdapter.CartProductViewHolder> {

    MyCartFragment myCartFragment = new MyCartFragment();
    public  List<CartProduct> cart_list = myCartFragment.cart_list;
    public  ArrayList<CartProduct> data = new ArrayList<>();
    public CartRecyclerAdapter(List<CartProduct> cart_list) {
        this.data.clear();
        data.addAll(cart_list);
    }

    public class CartProductViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
        View mView;
        TextView textView_name;
        TextView textView_quantity;
        TextView textView_price;
        TextView order_quantity;
        TextView order_price;
        ImageView imageView;
        ImageButton delete;
        public CartProductViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            mView = itemView;
            textView_name = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.cproductname);
            textView_price = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.cproductprice);
            textView_quantity = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.cproductQuantity);
            order_price = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.cuserprice);
            order_quantity  = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.cuserquantity);
            imageView = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.cproductimage);
            delete = (ImageButton) itemView.findViewById(R.id.cdeletebutton);   
            delete.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    int product_position = getAdapterPosition();
                    String pid = data.get(product_position).getId();
                    myCartFragment.removeitem(pid);
                    notifyDataSetChanged();                  
                }
            });
        }
        public void setName(String title) {
            textView_name.setText(title);
        }

        public void setQunatity(Double quantity) {
            textView_quantity.setText("Available Quantity: " + Double.toString(quantity));
        }
        public void setPrice(Double price) {
            textView_price.setText("Price: " + Double.toString(price));
        }
        public void setOrderPrice(Double cart_price) {
            order_price.setText("Price: " + Double.toString(cart_price));
        }
        public void setOrderQuantity(int cart_Quantity) {
            order_quantity.setText(Integer.toString(cart_Quantity));
        }
        public void setImage(String image) {
            Picasso.with(mView.getContext())
                    .load(image)
                    .placeholder(product)
                    .resize(1000,700)
                    .centerCrop()
                    .into(imageView);
        }
    }
    @Override
    public CartProductViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                .inflate(R.layout.product_cart_item, parent, false);

        return new CartProductViewHolder(itemView);
    }
    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(CartProductViewHolder holder, int position) {
        CartProduct cartProduct = data.get(position);
        holder.setName(cartProduct.getProductName());
        holder.setQunatity(cartProduct.getQuantity());
        holder.setPrice(cartProduct.getPrice());
        holder.setImage(cartProduct.getUri());
        holder.setOrderQuantity(cartProduct.getCart_quantity());
        holder.setOrderPrice(cartProduct.getCart_price());
    }
    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return data.size();
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you confirm if the list items (`cart_list`) received in the adapter's constructor, does not contain the older list items?

Comment: Can you share the code for your `removeitem()` function so we can see how you are trying to delete an item? From here it doesn't seem like there is any action being taken on the list itself. It also seems like you might get some problems by declaring a new fragment in your adapter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a method to remove the old data with the new data in your Adapter:

```
public class CartRecyclerAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<CartRecyclerAdapter.CartProductViewHolder> {

  ...

  public void swap(List<CartProduct> cartList) {
    data.clear();
    data.addAll(cartList);
    notifyDataSetChanged();
  }

}
```

Then, you can call it to update the list with:

```
yourAdapter.swap(cartList);
```

**Please check** your following code for error:

```
public class CartRecyclerAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<CartRecyclerAdapter.CartProductViewHolder> {

    MyCartFragment myCartFragment = new MyCartFragment();
    public  List<CartProduct> cart_list = myCartFragment.cart_list;

    ...
}
```

where the `myCartFragment` is instantiated then you try to get the list of the `CartProduct`. It will introduce a bug in your code as myCartFragment is not finished yet because of the asynchronous process in creating a fragment.

Comment: Your Answer too works!

Answer (score 0):

You have to remove data from the ArrayList also

```
delete.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            int product_position = getAdapterPosition();
            String pid = data.get(product_position).getId();
            myCartFragment.removeitem(pid);
            data.remove(product_position);
            notifyDataSetChanged();                  
        }
    });
```

Comment: Your answer works! @sasikumar